# How to click pop up window button in selenium with Pyhton

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python, browser-automation, selenium3

I want to click the "Akkoord" button but I am unable to do that. I already tried different methods but they are not working. Any help will be appreciated.
[image]

one of the codes I tried.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get('https://www.demorgen.be/nieuws')

time.sleep(20)
driver.find_elements_by_class_name('message-component message-button no-children pg-accept-button')[0].click()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**use xpath or css**

css :

```
[class="message-component message-button no-children pg-accept-button"]


driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('[class="message-component message-button no-children pg-accept-button"]')[0].click()
```

xpath:

```
//*[@class="message-component message-button no-children pg-accept-button"]

driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="message-component message-button no-children pg-accept-button"]')[0].click()
```

**find_elements_by_class_name expects single class name as argument** thats why its not working as space in class indicates multiple  classes.

THe find by class actually uses css under the hood. So if you want to find element having multiple class . You can replace space with '.' (THis works only in python)

```
driver.find_elements_by_class_name('message-component.message-button.no-children.pg-accept-button')[0].click()
```

## Update

The element is inside iframe

```
frame = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,
    "#sp_message_container_404503 iframe")))
driver.switch_to_frame(frame)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(
    '[class="message-component message-button no-children pg-accept-button"]').click()
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried your suggested methods but it's gave me the same error NoSuchElementException

Comment: @TauqeerSajid its inside iframe updated the answer

Comment: thanks problem solved

Comment: I follow the answer but I'm unable to make it work. I receive "TimeoutException". from selenium import webdriver from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager import time driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install()) driver.get('https://www.demorgen.be/nieuws') time.sleep(20) #driver.find_elements_by_class_name('message-component message-button no-children pg-accept-button')[0].click() frame = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#sp_message_container_404503 iframe"))) driver.switch_to_frame(frame) driver.find_element_by_css_s